# Ionic Control Pages

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to put on my app 3 page content in one .html file but I cant figure it out to do that. My .html page code is here:

```
<script id="templates/topList.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>

  </script>

  <script id="templates/topList2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>

  </script>
```

And my app.js is this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
     url: '/',
     templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })
    .state('registration', {
     url: '/registration',
     templateUrl: 'templates/registration.html',
     controller: 'RegistrationCtrl'
    })
    .state('code_entery_page', {
     url: '/code_entery_page',
     templateUrl: 'templates/code_entery_page.html',
     controller: 'code_entery_pageCtrl'
    })
    .state('registration-create-profile', {
     url: '/registration-create-profile',
     templateUrl: 'templates/registration-create-profile.html',
     controller: 'registration-create-profileCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.main-traveler-page', {
     url: '/main-traveler-page',
     templateUrl: 'templates/main-traveler-page.html',
     controller: 'main-traveler-pageCtrl'
    })

    .state('pinko.main-pinko-page', {
     url: '/main-pinko-page',
     templateUrl: 'templates/main-pinko-page.html',
     controller: 'main-pinko-pageCtrl'
    })



   .state('app', {
     url: '/app',
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: 'templates/directives/traveler-navigation.html',
     controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('pinko', {
     url: '/pinko',
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: 'templates/directives/pinko-navigation.html',
     controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })




  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

but I dont know how to connect to toplist.html and toplist2.html in app.js to work when my page is open?
In app.js - .state('pinko.main-pinko-page') is the page where i want to show toplist.html and toplist2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your both template in single html file like common-template.html.

And include this common-template in main-pinko-page.html as you mentioned in your question that's needed in .state('pinko.main-pinko-page').

If this one required in only one place use above case otherwise include this common-template in your main html file from where all the navigation initiates.

Comment: Some example? Just not following where to include?

Comment: When do you want add this?Like specific event or something?

Comment: I would like to add three types of some content on page main-pinko-page.html . I have on main-pinko-page.html top navigation with three picks. Example Navigation(Home/About/Contact), and for example on home click I would like to show content that is in 
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">Home text</script>

Comment: Rather doing this you could go with ngIf directive. As in you'll calling some function on clicking of (Home/etc/etc2) and setting kind of variable true/false based on click.

Comment: I've added one plunkr, check this out kind of work
https://plnkr.co/edit/vGyqZuKc54VloIkzRoHb?p=preview